# Best way to send image through GRPC using protobuf

Tags: python, image, serialization, grpc

I am currently using python grpc. My intention is to send an image to my GRPC server using the minimum payload size. My proto looks like the following:

```
message ImageBinaryRequest {
  // Image as bytes
  bytes image = 1;
}
```

And my client encode images like this:

```
def get_binary_request():
    image = (np.random.rand(1080, 1920, 3) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
    return cv2.imencode(".jpg", image)[1].tobytes()


channel = grpc.insecure_channel(grpc_url)
stub = inference_pb2_grpc.InferenceAPIsServiceStub(channel)

response= stub.BenchmarkBinaryImage(
    benchmark_pb2.ImageBinaryRequest(image=get_binary_request())
)
```

I was wondering if is this the optimal way to serialize and image through GRPC? Since payload size is the same as for REST:

```
requests.post(http_url, data=get_binary_request())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good way to send an image. gRPC does not have an intrinsic way to handle images. It uses same HTTP/2 underneath as the REST service so it is expected that the sizes are comparable.